# OpenVz VDS/VPS  настройки сервера для хостинrа сайтов

Tags: vps

Так и не нашел метки на hashcode.ru о настройках VDS/VPS для хостинга сайтов.Дайте пожалуйста хороший свежий мануал на установку (apache2,mysql,php,phpmyadmin)

Comment: На #amdin.hashcode.ru ни чего подобного не нашел:(

Comment: Три минуты погуглил:

1. http://filesd.net/stat/settingvps.php
2. http://komelin.com/content/bazovaya-nastroika-vps-khostinga-pod-ubuntu
3. http://hutpu4.net/puplication/%EF%BB%BFnastrojka-web-servera-na-osnove-vpsvds-v-ubuntudebian.html

Comment: Вы меня не правильно поняли , Я хочу что бы эта инфорамция находилась на #hashcode , я даже не буду заходить по вашим линкам...Мануал должен быть что бы пользователи могли  посмотреть подсказку от компетентных администраторов
VDS/VPS серверов. Может это звучит как то требовательно , но хотелось бы что бы это выглядело имено так ..

Comment: @MACJIO, со временем может что-то и изменится, но на данный момент, формат данного сервиса есть "**Вопрос - Ответ**", но не "**Хэшкодопедия**"

Comment: Не будем заглядывать в будущее ,а будем излогать и мыслить ..

Comment: #XэшКод форумы для: пользователей, администраторов, математиков и филологов.